# return a new object with keys from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new object from the `people` array below, using `born` as a key, that contains all the people born in that year:

```
 const newObject = {
      '1971': {
        male: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        female: [ [Object] ]
      },
      '1972': {
        male: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        female: [ [Object] ]
      }
    }
```

Here is my code so far:

```
people.map(person => {
  let {
    born,
    sex
  } = person;

  newPeople[born] = sex == "male" ? {
    male: Array.isArray(male) && array.length ? male.push(person) : [],
    female: Array.isArray(female) && female.length ? female.push(person) : []}
})
```

Array of people:

```
const people = [{
    name: 'Jim',
    sex: 'male',
    born: '1971',
    address: {
      town: 'London',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    sex: 'male',
    born: '1971',
    address: {
      town: 'London',
    },
  },....
```

jsfiddle setup here: https://jsfiddle.net/jw9n3bmr/

Comment: Please don't use `.map` for simple array iteration. Use `forEach` or an actual loop for that.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `reduce` for what you want to do:

```js
const people = [{
    name: 'Jim',
    sex: 'male',
    born: '1971',
    address: {
      town: 'London',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    sex: 'male',
    born: '1971',
    address: {
      town: 'London',
    },
  }
];
  
const result = people.reduce((acc, currVal) => {
  (acc[currVal.born] || (acc[currVal.born] = { male: [], female: [] }))[currVal.sex].push(currVal);
  return acc;
}, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could helps.

```
const getItems = (array, key, value) => {
    let items = [];
    array.forEach((k, o) => { if (o[key] === value) items.push(o) });
    return items;
};

console.log(getItems(people, "born", "1971"));
```